# jest - how to disable puppeteer 5 logs?

Tags: logging, jestjs, puppeteer

Starting with puppeteer v5, my jest tests flood the console with puppeteer debug messages, e.g.
`puppeteer:protocol:RECV ◀: {"method":"Network.loadingFinished","params":{"requestId":"xxxxxx.xx","timestamp":xxxxxx.xxxxxx,"encodedDataLength":xxxx,"shouldReportCorbBlocking":false},"sessionId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}`

test.spec.js:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

describe('puppeteer-test', () => {
  it('works', async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppeteer");
    await browser.close();
  });
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "5.0.0",
    "jest": "26.1.0"
  }
}
```

to execute: `node_modules/.bin/jest`

How can I turn off these messages?

Comment: Watch this issue on Github https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6147